# Finiteness of $H^2(X,\mu_n)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, flat-cohomology

Let $X$ be a proper curve over $k$ (algebraically closed) of characteristic $p>0$.

When is $H_{fl}^2(X,\mu_n)$ is a finite group?

It's true when $X$ is smooth but are there any more general results?

Comment: If the Picard scheme of $X$ has any addtive subgroups, then the Kummer sequence implies that the group is not finite. If the Picard scheme is semi-abelian, then you can prove finiteness using the vanishing of the Brauer group of any curve over an algebraically closed field (Grothendieck: Groupe de Brauer III, Corollaire 1.2)